# Change value of Onclick function vars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the onClick function attached to a button. I want to be able to change the function var from 'create' to 'update' on the page load and through other functions. I have tried the code below but no luck.

```
<input type="button" name="save_customer" id="save_customer" value="Save" onClick="customer_crud('create')" />

var js = "customer_crud('read')";
// create a function from the "js" string
var newclick = new Function(js);
// clears onclick then sets click using jQuery
$("#save_customer").attr('onClick', '').click(newclick)
```

Any ideas.

**UPDATED**

Ok in a nutshell i want to change the attr onClick like you would change the attr name & type.

```
<input type="button" name="save_customer" id="save_customer" value="Save" onClick="customer_crud('create')" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="save_customer" id="save_customer" value="Save" onClick="customer_crud('update')" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#save_customer").click(function(){
    customer_crud("read");
});
```

Is how you would do this.

**EDIT:**

```
$("#save_customer").click(function(){
    customer_crud("update");
});
```

In jQuery you can set the value of the "onClick" attribute/event with `.click(function(){/* Attribute content */});`

Comment: @motionman95 - This will not work as the save_customer button is used to create a entry and update through the same button that why i need to change attr onClick="customer_crud('create')" to onClick="customer_crud('update')" once data has been added.

Comment: Then once the data has been added, you'd just do my code with the change of 'read' to 'update'?

Comment: @motionman95 - will not work as your way the button will not change to update but will always run customer_crud('read'). Am i not explaining with right or something?

Comment: *twitch* OK, in jQuery you can always set the "onClick" event with .click(). So if you want the onClick's attribute to become 'customer_crud("update")', you would do (see edit).

Comment: @motionman95 - I have done it the way to have said and it will always run the update function when i click the button. I want to change the onclick from another function that runs when i update.

Comment: OK then, then in that function you would just do `$("#save_customer").click(function(){ /* change this to the new onclick attribute */ });`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline handlers if possible.  They don't get proper scope, and also rely on the highly-frowned upon `eval` to do their work.

Instead, in your `.js` file, you can just do this:

```
var action = 'create';
$('#save_customer').click(function() {
      customer_crud(action);
      action = 'update';
});
```

The first time the handler is invoked it'll do `create`, and then subsequently do an `update`.

I put a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/QzaXU/

Comment: Thanks I thought I could change the onClick attr but ill just add a if statment to change it back to create. Thanks again.

Comment: 'onclick' etc are pretty much deprecated and shouldn't be used.